# Need Output of query as column

Tags: t-sql

HI

Actually I need a query like:

```
select x from a as col1 ,
select y from b as col2 ,
select Z from c as col3
```

and the output should be like

```
col1 | col2 | col3


 x   |  y   |  z
```

Comment: Do you have any common columns in the tables a, b and c? so that you can get the output in the format you given.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that tables a, b and c does not have more than one row you can do this.

```
select 
(select x from a) as col1 ,
(select y from b) as col2 ,
(select Z from c) as col3
```